# Typescript static class generic functions

Tags: typescript, generics

Trying to understand typescript generics + static class functions a bit more thoroughly, and I am running into to some type problems:

```
class Base {
  value : string = 'default'

  static identity<M extends typeof Base>() : M  {
    return this // Type Error: Type 'typeof Base' is not assignable to type 'M'
  }
}

class Extended extends Base {
  otherValue = 'extended'

  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

let baseClass = Base.identity()
let extendedClass = Extended.identity()
expect(new baseClass().value).to.eq('default')

// Type Error: Property 'otherValue' does not exist on type 'Base'
// How do I make Extended.identity() be `typeof Extended` without
// an explicit cast?
expect(new extendedClass().otherValue).to.eq('extended')
```

If I ignore type errors and run the output code, everything runs as expected and expectations are met. I think this is probably due to some understanding gaps with static functions, but any help in understanding the problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is [polymorphic `this` on static methods](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), which TypeScript doesn't directly support.  What it *does* seem to support (and it's [mentioned in that Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863#issuecomment-242782664)), is using [`this` parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions) on the method:

```
class Base {
  value : string = 'default'

  // specify that this is M
  static identity<M extends typeof Base>(this: M) : M  {
    return this; 
  }
}

class Extended extends Base {
  otherValue = 'extended'

  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
```

The static `identity()` method will only work if the object on which you call it is assignable to a subtype of the `Base` constructor type.  The compiler apparently will use type inference to determine the right value for `M` when you call it.  You can verify that things behave as expected:

```
let baseClass = Base.identity() // Base.identity<typeof Base>
let extendedClass = Extended.identity() // Base.identity<typeof Extended>
```

It's not well documented, and it frankly surprised me that you can actually get it to work.  If you really want polymorphic `this` in static methods to work without the above voodoo, you might want to go to [Microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) and give the issue a  or describe your use-case if you think it's particularly compelling.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that M is more concrete than Base, and you are trying to assign Base to M. Imagine this:

- You have your class `Base`
- Another class extends `Base` -> `Base+A` (A indicates additional properties that the less generic class has)
- You invoke `Base.identity` method on `Base+A` class:

  ```
  identity<Base+A extends typeof Base>(): Base+A {
    return this; // This is a Base class method, so it's typeof Base
  }
  ```

  Compiler does not find the A part in the return value's type, so it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Extends @jcalz 's answer to support instance type (works on ts@3.5):

```
class A {
  static a<T extends typeof A>(this: T) {
    return new this();
  }

  static b<T extends typeof A, I = InstanceType<T>>(this: T): I {
    return (new this()) as I;
  }
}

class B extends A {}

let a = A.a();  // type: A
let b = B.a();  // type: A

let a2 = A.b(); // type: A
let b2 = B.b(); // type: B
```

Comment: I'm on typescript 4.7.4, and this would work if the second generic argument of b was `I extends A = InstanceType<T>`.